# Fix header on top with kable or DT

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt, kable

I'm trying to include a vertically scrollable table in my html output. The table looks stunning, but I would like to fix the header on top (while right now it scrolls up like everything else). A plus would be being able to filter the columns as well, or interact with them (e.g. sorting).

I have tried using both kable() + kableExtra() and DT(). My understanding is it would be easier with DT, but I find the documentation very confusing.

I'm doing something like this:

```
library(datasets)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(DT)

data(iris)

# with kable
kable(iris, "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "responsive"), 
                full_width = F) %>%
  scroll_box(width = "100%", height = "400px")

# with DT
datatable(showData, options = list("scrollY"))
```

I can't really find a way to fix the header on top or add filters. Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Update: I've updated DT() and the table now is more functional. You can order the columns, but it isn't scrollable and you can't filter. It's also quite ugly. Will update further if I solve this...

Comment: See **10. Scroller** here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html This is not what you want ?

Comment: Thanks! More or less! The biggest problem is that one of my columns has a lot of text. With kable() it shows in small paragraphs, going to the next line. In DT(), the column becomes very large allowing scrolling, which is inconvenient... Moreover, with horizontal scrolling the header stays fixed, which makes the header and the cells not allineate.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine custom CSS with kable to create a scrollable table body with fixed header.

For example, create file **styles.css** in project directory with the following content:

```css
.table-fixed-header tbody{
  display:block;
  overflow:auto;
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
}
.table-fixed-header thead tr{
  display:table-header-group;
  height:100%;
}
```

In YAML of .Rmd document, refer to styles.css:

```
output: 
html_document:
    css: styles.css
```

In R code chunk, pass style name to the kable() function

```
kable(iris, escape = F, table.attr='class="table-fixed-header"') %>%
  kable_styling()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could've also added

fixed_thead = T

in the scroll box.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).